# Reset Database in JPA Hibernate with SPRING MVC

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

I have a requirement where i want to clear whole database tables and than move ahead.

I found below solution in hibernate with LocalSessionFactoryBean.

https://code.google.com/p/ormunit/source/browse/trunk/ormunit-hibernate/src/main/java/net/chrisrichardson/ormunit/hibernate/ResetDatabaseByRecreatingSchemaStrategy.java

But i am using JPA over Hibernate as a result i am having LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.

Can anyone guide me, how i can achieve similar solution using JPA over hibernate.

Motive is to Reset Database

Comment: do you want to do this on startup or at run time?

Comment: what JPA implmentation are you using ?

Comment: I want to do this at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used

> SchemaExport

to solve this issue,

```
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = getLocalSessionFactoryBean(applicationContext);

        Configuration conf = new Ejb3Configuration().configure(
                localSessionFactoryBean.getPersistenceUnitInfo(), null)
                .getHibernateConfiguration();
        SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport(conf, localSessionFactoryBean
                .getDataSource().getConnection());
        export.create(true, true);


public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getLocalSessionFactoryBean(
            ApplicationContext applicationContext) {

        return (LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) applicationContext
                .getBean(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With hibernate you could set  `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>` or create-drop.

You could also use [dbunit](http://www.dbunit.org/).